# UINavigationViewContoller's rightBarButtonItem disappears once the application is pushed to background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have added `rightBarButtonItem` in a `viewcontroller` under `viewWillAppear`. its showing the button corretly.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

UIBarButtonItem *addBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add_Clicked:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBarButtonItem;
}
```

but once i pushed application in background and bring it(applcation) to foreground the rightBarButtonItem got diappear?

I have debug that viewWillAppear get called once Application bring back to forground and the above line of code get executed also but then also the button does not comes up.

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear` is only called when you push a view on to the stack.

Place you code in the `viewDidLoad`.

When your app is send to the background, the `viewDidUnload` will be called, to reduce memory.
But sine your view is already presented it will not call the `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I do the same in my app and there is work correctly, then there is an other error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this in a new Navigation-based project and I couldn't reproduce this.

One thing you can try is to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` or check, if you setting the rightBarButtonItem to nil somewhere else.

Comment: i have called [super viewWillAppear:animated] and also checked that no where i have set rightBarButtonItem as nil.

Comment: u can disable the background support and from info.plist file and then try to simulate the same

Comment: If I disable background support, the app starts normaly and the button appears. Maybe you shoud post more code of the view controller.

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 if (DEBUG) NSLog(@"view will appear");
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 
  
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    UIBarButtonItem *addBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add_Clicked:)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBarButtonItem;
   [addBarButtonItem release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 [super viewDidUnload];
}

Comment: I just tested your code and everything works fine in my project. If you don't mind, send the complete project to the_audience(at)gmx(dot)de.